# ISP injected ads prevent js from running properly

Tags: javascript

The ISP just modified our web page by injecting ad links. like this speech balloon:
[image]

The icon tricks our user to click on their ads.

This is not enough for them, they don't write the code properly, they just caused our app to crush, like this:
[image]

I know the how that happened, they just used jQuery before it even loaded.

This is the embedded code:
[image]

I know that I can fire a complain to the ISP or even sue them but, that's not a certain win.

I need a certain way to remove those ads.

A javascript? A certain available frontend technology?

Whatever it is, I really will appreciate.

Comment: Are you serving content over HTTPS?

Comment: Oh my! Is that simple? I will try. A big thanks.

Comment: Well that's why I'm asking.  If you already are, then the problem isn't with your ISP, it's something on your own box.  If you aren't, then you should because the ISP won't be able to modify your content over the wire.  Additionally, how is this content hosted?  Is your ISP hosting it, or are you on a VPS?

Comment: It worked!! I didn't realize they modify the content on the fly. silly me. Really thank you.

Comment: @zero298 It hosted in the cloud. And we have https but I didn't force to redirect to https. Now it work out perfectly. Clean and Clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [let's encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) and move your website to https only.